# HTML table with raised column effect

Tags: html, css

I've got a bit of a challenge with an HTML table that we need to have raised columns. If you look at the attached image you'll see what I mean. 
[image: raised column effect - table]
The purpose of these raised columns is to draw the user's attention to them.

The problem is:

1. To get the effect of the column raising above the other columns you
   need some kind of element/height/margin to appear outside the
   boundary of the table, which doesn't seem to work
2. Same goes for the bottom
3. To have the drop shadow appear correctly, it needs to be applied to all the cells in a column.

We did get this to work by splitting it up into multiple tables then applying the styles to the table that should be the raised column. The image I've attached is actually a live table working like this. 
But, you loose all other needed features of tables...

1. Row heights don't match if the text wraps in table 1 but not in
   table 2.
2. To deal with the row height issue we applied a fixed height to each table's rows, but then you have to force text to not wrap. If you then get text that's longer than the width you run into trouble.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved without splitting the tables?

Thanks, 
jacques

Comment: if you can use jQuery, consider using a [zoom plugin](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-image-zoom.html)

Comment: How would zoom work with a table and raised columns? Zoom seems to be for images. ?

Comment: There's only one thing I can think of which let's you change some column properties while preserving table structure:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html but that will only give you varied border and background color... Still might be an option if your UI designers aren't too picky.

Comment: Maybe write your table into a canvas and zoom it in there

Comment: I would probably use two tables, but generate the second one dynamically with JavaScript, and recalculate it on resize. So declare a table as normal, perhaps add custom `data-*` attributes to the cells you want to raise, and then attach some script which would clone the appropriate cells and position them accordingly. This is a pain, but it does work (I've used a similar technique for fixed header/footers), degrades well without script, and allows you to still declare just one table with tabular data.

Comment: You could try a virtual table made up of `<div>`s and with `display:table` and co. applied to them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try having an extra row for the table above the header row (you may have to stop using any `th` tags) to give you the overbar at the top. Similarly for the bottom, an extra highlighting row.

Although you have to compromise the table a little to do that, it is better in my book than separating into 2 tables, as that defeats all the purposes of the table tag; to show a table, and have that table easily declared.

The effects inside the table are probably best done with jquery, unless the choice of highlighted columns is entirely static, in which case consider rendering a static html version by generating the html appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Phil, that sounds like a good idea (additional rows), but what were you suggesting about the box-shadow? That's actually the part that's giving me the most hassles at the moment. 

With box shadow you can't have it displayed on the left and right for example, there's just not enough control. And if you apply it to each of the cells in a column the shadow effect appears at the intersection of each cell as well, which was surprising.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not enough control'? Can you demo in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Phil, by control I mean that you don't seem to be able to control the box shadow to appear on the left and right side 'only'. I thought that it would work for the table TD elements, but for some reason the box shadow appears above each cell's background color so it ends up looking a mess. I will try and put something together in jsfiddle